# Phonegap Build - local notification plugin server request

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I want to check if there are any new messages on my server. If yes, then display a notification. I am using local-notification plugin. 
**The problem is, the code doesn't work when app is closed...**

My code in index.html

```
setInterval() { 
        $(".news_div").load ("http://www.website.com/news");  

 },7000);
```

And on the server

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
   text: "Hi user"
});
```

Thanks

Comment: It won't. Your webview runs within your app only when it's in the foreground.

Comment: I would suggest you look into push notifications GCM and APN.  In short, your server will send a notification to Google/Apple messaging services (when you need to notify a user of a new message).  Your message will then be sent to your users' respective device, which they could click to open your app.  If your app is already open then you can trigger a custom event to popup a message for example.